# Got error in VS code terminal but got results in jupyter notebook for the same code

Tags: python, html, selenium, visual-studio-code

Please I tried web scraping using python and selenium. I'm curious why I get an error in VS code terminal `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//small/span"}` but get results when I run in jupyter notebook, for the same code.

Code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://search.cac.gov.ng/list")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="results"]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/input[1]').send_keys('new york')

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="results"]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/input[2]').click()

driver.implicitly_wait(3)

RC = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//small/span').text

print(RC)
```

Trackback:

````
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Users\ooffodum001\Desktop\kyc test\test.py", line 24, in <module>
        goal = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//small/span').text
      File "C:\Users\ooffodum001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1238, 
    in find_element
        return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
      File "C:\Users\ooffodum001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "C:\Users\ooffodum001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//small/span"}
      (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.93)
    Stacktrace:
    Backtrace:
            Ordinal0 [0x00806903+2517251]
            Ordinal0 [0x0079F8E1+2095329]
            Ordinal0 [0x006A2848+1058888]
            Ordinal0 [0x006CD448+1233992]
            Ordinal0 [0x006CD63B+1234491]
            Ordinal0 [0x006F7812+1406994]
            Ordinal0 [0x006E650A+1336586]
            Ordinal0 [0x006F5BBF+1399743]
            Ordinal0 [0x006E639B+1336219]
            Ordinal0 [0x006C27A7+1189799]
            Ordinal0 [0x006C3609+1193481]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00995904+1577972]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00A40B97+2279047]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00896D09+534521]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00895DB9+530601]
            Ordinal0 [0x007A4FF9+2117625]
            Ordinal0 [0x007A98A8+2136232]
            Ordinal0 [0x006C27A7+1189799]
            Ordinal0 [0x006C3609+1193481]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00995904+1577972]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00A40B97+2279047]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00896D09+534521]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00895DB9+530601]
            Ordinal0 [0x007A4FF9+2117625]
            Ordinal0 [0x007A98A8+2136232]
            Ordinal0 [0x007A99E2+2136546]
            Ordinal0 [0x007B3541+2176321]
            BaseThreadInitThunk [0x759E6359+25]
            RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77EB87A4+228]
            RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77EB8774+180]```
````

Thanks

Comment: Can you share what you are trying so far ?

Comment: Please, post your code [mre], as well as full traceback you get.

Comment: just did, thanks

Comment: The code that you have provided is not reproducible. It does not contain any element `//small/span`. From your code, it seems that you are entering some word/words in the search box and clicking in search. But, maybe you have edited the code before pasting it here. Please provide more details. Also, if your code is working in Jupyter and not in VScode. Then, probably you have to increase the wait time before your code searches for `//small/span`.

Comment: @fam yes, it's a search. Every search result contains an RC number which is contained in a span. That's the content I want to scrape. Done that in jupyter with the same code above but isn't working with vscode.